# false statement not executed by ternary operator

Tags: javascript, php, web, twig

In the following code, the ternary operator isn't assigning the value if condition returns false!

```
<script>
                function lgn() {
                    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none' ? 'block':'none';
                    document.getElementById('lgn').style.display = 'none' ? 'block':'none';
                }
</script>
```

I am actually trying to make a overlay over my webpage, following is the Twig:

```
<div class="nvg">
                <ul>
                    {% block links %}
                    <li class="n.link"><span class="fa fa-times close" onclick="lgn()"></span></li>
                    {% endblock %}
                </ul>
</div>
```

AND

```
{% block overlay %}
        {{ form_start(form, {'attr':{'id':'lgn'}}) }}
        <span class="fa fa-times close" onclick="lgn()"></span><br />
        <span>Login:</span>
        {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr':{'placeholder':'email'}}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.pass, {'attr':{'placeholder':'password','class':'pass'}}) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Please help...

Comment: `'none'` evaluates to `true`, so it will never return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ternary doesn't make sense.

```
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none' ? 'block':'none';
```

There's no logical evaluation to make, and the string will (mostly) always be evaluated to true. Do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = (document.getElementById('overlay').style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Your best solution (in terms of cleanliness) is to make the selectors into variables.

```
function lgn() {
    element1 = document.getElementById('overlay');
    element1.style.display = (element1.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';

    element2 = document.getElementById('lgn');
    element2.style.display = (element2.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The ternary makes a boolean decisions, and you've written yours to always evaluate to true:

```
'none' ? 'block':'none';
```

is basically the same as

```
if ('none' is true) { 
   'block'
} else {
   'none';
}
```

Since `none` as a string is a truthy (evaluates to the same as boolean true in most cases), you always pick the "true" path in the ternary.

Comment: I like this answer, I think it would be better if you added a solution along with the great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You **always** assign the `display` to `'block'` because the `'none'` is a non-empty *string* and it is **always** *true*

```
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none' ? 'block':'none';
```

Use this statement

```
var display = document.getElementById('overlay').style.display
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = display == 'none' ? 'block':'none';
```

Comment: Why set `display` then use `document.getElementById('overlay').style.display` again?

Comment: Yes, I understand. But you can use `display` to replace `document.getElementById('overlay').style.display` in the second line also.

Comment: Yes, it's the same, I think it's more readable than as `document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = (document.getElementById('overlay').style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';`

Comment: Yes, it is. But as you posted above, you can also use `display = display == 'none' ? 'block':'none';`

Comment: @Daniel No, You cannot,  it changes the `display` only not `document.getElementById('overlay').style.display`